# Darwin term in positronium

Tags: positronium

Darwin term in Hydrogen atom has the form (in natural units)
$$
V_{Darwin}=\frac{\alpha}{8m^2} 4\pi \delta(\vec{r})
$$
My question is this: is the $m$ in the denominator electron mass, or the reduced mass $1/\mu= 1/m_e + 1/m_p$? For Hydrogen it doesn't matter much, but if I'm looking at positronium, then the difference is a factor of 4.